# Store a tf.Saver.save checkpoint in a variable (or in memory)

Tags: tensorflow

I am using Tensorflow and storing the current "best" model on the hard drive for persistence, using `tf.Saver`:

```
saver = tf.train.Saver(max_to_keep=1)

[...]

saver.save(
    sess,
    path_to_file,
    global_step=epoch
)
```

My network is rather small and very fast to run, a single epoch on the GPU runs in less than 10 seconds. However, saving the model to the hard drive takes between one to two minutes, taking up a lot time.

Is it possible to store the model in memory, to avoid taking up such a big chunk of the overall run time? If I somehow could store the "best" model in memory for a while, and dump it once I tell the model to, I could cut down the overall run time by a big factor.

I've looked at the `tf.Saver` documentation and implementation, and I can not see any way to achieve just what I want. Is there some other implementation or tool that can do what I want to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think `tf.Saver` supports this. You can, however, mount an in-memory filesystem (like tmpfs in linux) and save to that directory, which should not touch any disks.